# Find the formula to get the P Value associated with Hypothesis test.

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Consider a random sample of 11 observations, given in the following, from a
normal population with hypothesized mean 57.71.

59.94 58.93 59.41 60.66 59.00 60.98 58.85 55.21 59.02 61.14 59.25

Compute the value of the test statistic for H0 : µ = 57.71 versus Ha : µ > 57.71 with α = 0.01. Draw a conclusion about the population mean.

**Write down the formula to get the p value associated with this hypothesis test**

- For the first part, I found the SD and it came out to be around **1.603650835**
- Based on the SD, I found the "t". **t = 0.997723422**
- Now To find the P-Value, i need to know the DF but I am not to sure what the DF would be.

So I am assuming that DF is the Sample Size (11 in this case - 1 = 10). A lot of resources said to use Minitab or R to find the P value but I am not allowed to use any of that. I am pretty sure that there is a manual way to find out the P value. So can someone help me find the P-Value or the steps I have to take to get to the P-Value.

Comment: Those do not look particularly likely to be normally distributed, since ten of the values are between $58.85$ and $61.64$ while the other one is $55.21$, though it is not impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should say that you calculated the mean to be about $\bar{x}=59.30818$ as well as your sample standard deviation of $s=1.603650835$

You have miscalculated $t$: it should then be $\sqrt{n}\left( \dfrac{\bar{x}-57.71}{s}\right)$ which is about $3.3$ here.  Your calculation was a factor of $\sqrt{11}$ too small; perhaps you forgot that the standard error of the mean is smaller than the standard deviation of the distribution

I have some doubts whether you are going to be able to find a $p$-value without tables or a computer

Comment: Well can you tell me how would i Use tables to get the P-Value if it's manually not possible. Please and Thank you. And thank you pointing out the mistake.

Comment: If your table looks something like the one at https://www2.palomar.edu/users/rmorrissette/Lectures/Stats/ttests/TTable.jpg then you are interested in the $df=10$ row.  Your $t$ value should be between the values $3.169$ (critical values of $\alpha=0.005$ one tailed and $\alpha=0.01$ two tailed) and $3.581$ ($\alpha=0.0025$ one tailed and $\alpha=0.005$ two tailed).  From your alternative hypothesis, you seem to be interested in a one tailed test, so you have $0.005 \lt p \lt  0.0025$ making this significant at the $\alpha = 0.01$ level. In fact $p \approx 0.04$

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much.

Comment: and I should have said $p\approx 0.004$.  With a computer you could use the R code something like the following: `dat <- c(59.94,58.93,59.41,60.66,59.00,60.98,58.85,55.21,59.02,61.14, 59.25); 
t.test(dat, mu=57.71, alternative = c("greater"))`